# Enclosing the function call in another function call (retval as parameter)

Tags: vim

Having this LOC:

```
printf("%s (%d)\t(%d)\t%d-%d\t", meta_scanner_token_name($ret['major']), $ret['major'], (string)$ret['dirty'], $ret['start_line'], $ret['minor']);
```

What is the fastest way in terms of key strokes to enclose the call to `meta_scanner_token_name` in another function call to `foo`, yelding:

```
printf("%s (%d)\t(%d)\t%d-%d\t", foo(meta_scanner_token_name($ret['major'])), $ret['major'], (string)$ret['dirty'], $ret['start_line'], $ret['minor']);
```

given that

1. **first scenario**: my cursor is on 'm' at the beginning of the function?
2. **second scenario**: my cursor is somewhere on `meta_scanner_token_name`?

`va)oB` would select the entire line, and `ys%)` would enclose only the `m`, resulting in:

```
... (m)eta_sca...
```

Please answer to **both scenarios**.

*(I am using [spf13-vim](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/) with default settings except some visual changes, if that has any relevance)*

Comment: I made a plugin based on tpope's vim-surround that includes this: but more generally [vim-surround-funk](https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/vim-surround-funk) also allows you to delete, change and yank a surrounding function call, and paste it around any text object (and there's a text object for function calls, so you can paste it around them too!) So in this case you would do `gSaf` to grip/surround (`gS` operator) around function (`af` is a text object for a function call) and then just write 'foo'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `ifoo(<Esc>` then `f)i)<Esc>`
2. `bifoo(<Esc>` then `f)i)<Esc>`

but I'm still a Vim noob

-- EDIT --

I see "Surrounding.vim" is a modified version of "Surround.vim" if it's compatible with Surround you can do:

**Scenario 1**

```
vt,sffoo<CR>
```

1. `vt,` to select everything until the first `,`
2. `s` to launch Surround.vim
3. `f` to instruct Surround to input a "function"
4. `foo` the identifier
5. `<CR>` Enter key.

That's 6 keystrokes not including typing `foo` which — I think — can't really be avoided.

**Scenario 2**

```
bvt,sffoo<CR>
```

It's the same as scenario 1 except that you type `b` first to go back to the first letter of `meta_scanner_token_name`.

Comment: spf13-vim has a plugin which automatically closes any typed (, so this won't work just like that and at the same time, as I said, I'm looking for the fastest way to do it. I won't downvote this though, since you say you're a noob with vim, just like me.

Answer (score 2):

Using normal vim you could do this (prefix with `b` for scenario 2)

```
`cf)foo()<esc>P`
```

If your vim plugins add the closing paren for you, you can drop that from the sequence. Depending on where it leaves your cursor, you might need to use `p` instead of `P`.